# Complex "as label" for comprehension expression in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can you set a complex 'as label' in a comprehension expression in angular?

This may be very simple, and I'm just not getting it, or it could be impossible, but I've looked everywhere and I can find no hints towards a solution. The only work around I've found is to pre-populate the 'as label' attribute of the object with the exact string you want before using it in the comprehension expression (which I'd like to avoid).

For example, I have an object like this:

```
$scope.projects = [{
  "description": "Asset Management",
  "code": "ASSET",
  "fieldName": "Asset Evaluation Level"
},
{
  "description": "Checklist",
  "code": "CHECK",
  "fieldName": "Checklist Scores"
},
{
  "description": "IT Support",
  "code": "IT",
  "fieldName": "IT Support Ticket Number"
}]
```

I have a select with ng-options:

```
<select ng-model="jiraProject" class="form-control" ng-options="option as option.description for option in projects"></select>
```

I want the options 'as' label to appear in the select dropdown like this:

"Asset Management (ASSET)", "Checklist (CHECK)", "IT Support (IT)"

Maybe through syntax like this?:

```
option as {options.description (option.code)} for option in projects
```

Thanks for any and all feedback in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this :

```
<select ng-model="jiraProject" class="form-control" ng-options="option as option | formatOption for option in projects"></select>
```

and this :

```
yourModule.filter('formatOption', [function(){
    return function( option ){
      return option.description + ' (' + option.code + ')';
    };
}]);
```

Angularjs filters are so awesome :-)

Comment: I hadn't even considered filters! They truly are awesome!!! I'll have to study up on all their uses after this!

Comment: You're welcome :-) think of using filters whenever you have to make data go through a "pipe". It tricks you into doing functional programming and that is cool :p